# Why is a Post call routed to a Post method with a different signature?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller, repository, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two methods named Post* in my Web API server:

Controller

```
public void PostNoBills(int accountid, string name)
{
    duckbillsRepository.Post(accountid, name);
}

public void Post(NoBills noBills)
{
    duckbillsRepository.Post(noBills); 
}
```

Repository:

```
public void PostNoBills(int accountid, string name)
{
    int maxId = noBills.Max(d => d.Id);
    NoBills duckbill = new NoBills();
    duckbill.Id = maxId + 1;
    duckbill.AccountId = accountid;
    duckbill.Name = name;
    NoBills.Add(duckbill);
}

public void Post(NoBills noBills)
{
    int maxId = NoBills.Max(d => d.Id);
    NoBills.Id = maxId + 1;
    NoBills.Add(noBills);
}
```

So when I call a Post method from the client, passing an int and a string:

```
string uri = String.Format("http://platypi:28642/api/NoBills/{0}/{1}", onAccountOfWally, moniker);
var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = String.Format("{0}/{1}", onAccountOfWally, moniker);
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
```

...I expect the method with the "int accountid, string name" arguments to be the one that gets called, but it's not - the other one (the one accepting "NoBills noBills" as its argument) is. Why?

(BTW, I'm not at all sure the client code above is "right")

### UPDATE

In acquiescence to the invitation/demand of Kian Challa, here is WebApiConfig:

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

```
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiWithParameters",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ID}/{CountToFetch}"
        //defaults: new { ID = RouteParameter.Optional, CountToFetch = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiWith3Parameters",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ID}/{packSize}/{CountToFetch}"
        //defaults: new { ID = RouteParameter.Optional, packSize = RouteParameter.Optional, CountToFetch = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

As a bonus, here is RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

...and the perhaps pertinent piece of Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

### UPDATE 2

In reply to Kian Challa's comment below containing "*on the action public void PostNoBills(int accountid, string name)*"

Okay, so that is (if you're talking about the Controller code):

```
public void PostNoBills(int accountid, string name)
{
    duckbillsRepository.Post(accountid, name);
}
```

How should it be changed with:

```
[Route("api/nobills/{accountid}/{name}")]
```

? You imply that I need add nothing to WebApiConfig ("...*instead of creating a new route in WebApiConfig.cs*...") so...precisely what do I need to add, and where do I need to add it?

Comment: action selection depends on current request's route values and available actions and their parameters...so could you share how your routes look like?

Comment: Do you mean what's in WebApiConfig? What I find odd is that it does select one of the methods, but the "wrong" one.

Comment: if all your webapi routes are defined in WebApiConfig, then yes..

Comment: Okay, I updated my post with the contents of WebApiConfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action's FromUri parameters can be bound to route data or query string values with names `accountid` and `name` in this case...since none of your routes have these route variable names Web API is unable to provide any route data with names like `accountid` and `name` and hence your expected action isn't getting called...to resolve this issue, instead of creating a new route in WebApiConfig.cs, why not use attribute routing as you seem to be already calling that...Example: `[Route("api/nobills/{accountid}/{name}")]`

Comment: All down but nine, pard; set 'em up on the other alley. Where would I add "[Route("api/nobills/{accountid}/{name}")]"?

Comment: on the action `public void PostNoBills(int accountid, string name)`

Comment: i meant on the controller's 'action' and not on your repository code...since you are already calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` in WebApiConfig.cs, Web API will pickup all `Route` attributes decorated on actions/controllers..

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: That (Update 2) does show the controller's action - it is not the repository code (both can be seen in the original post; I misidentified the source (origin) of the source (code) in Update 2; I will update that update.